# Module output not added to display when using ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: modelbuilder, arcgis-pro

I have a model that runs fine in ArcMAP and adds the data to display if run in edit mode. I have now "converted" the module to ArcGIS Pro and it runs as it should. The only issue is that for some reason it does not add the data to display regardless if the model is run through dialogue box or edit mode. 
Please advice.

Comment: Does anyone know what to do to make it work? Does the toolbox with the model have to be converted to ArcGIS Pro to work properly?

Comment: Try making the output a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the model for the output object right click it and select Add to Display option, save the model, validate it, and run it again.

Comment: I have tried that but it did not work

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a bug again. Not working for me either. You have to make it a parameter to activate the "add to display".